# Parse calculations tokens

Tags: java

I have got a string, say, "5+30" and I need to parse it to tokens 5,30,+. How do I do that? Instead of "+" there can be any arithmetic operator? I think regular expressions will do but I am not a dab at them. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Will your expressions have parenthesis?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1320891/java-rpn-reverse-polish-notation-infix-to-postfix and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4240595/getting-wrong-outputs-in-infix-to-postfix-application-with-java seem to cover infix-to-postfix conversion in Java.

Comment: No, they will not. Just a simple calculator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example using the [`Scanner`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner("53+12-1+12");
String token;
while (null != (token = s.findInLine("\\d+|[+-]")))
    System.out.println(token);
```

Output: ([ideone.com demo](http://ideone.com/lH8Gv))

```
53
+
12
-
1
+
12
```

Note however, that if you're trying to *evaluate* the expression this will be of limited help as you will still have to take care of **operator precedence** and possible parenthisation. I would recommend you to use a proper parser generator for such task.

Comment: Another solution to the same problem using Scanner is at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350312/reading-char-array-of-number-more-than-10/3351024#3351024

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're trying to write some kind of arithmetic processor, so I'll suggest you use a parser generator like [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/). It has a tutorial on writing an arithmetic grammar.

Parser generators are very general so it might be overkill for your project, but it's still worth a look. It's always going to be useful to know how (and, more importantly, when) to use a parser generator.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you would use a scanner.  Here is an example of a scanner written in java : http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/scanning.html

You can also use java.util.Scanner -- here is tutorial :
http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/java.util/scanning-text-with-java.util.scanner-3.html

Answer (score 0):

A regex that should work for you is:

```
[0-9]+|[^0-9]+
```

You would use the java String match or Matcher classes to do the work for you

You can replace the [^0-9]+ part with the set of operators you want to support, for example:

```
[0-9]+|[+-/*]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can look at [pattern](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for good documentation.
You String will correspond to something like `[0-9]+\p{Punct}{1}[0-9]+`
There is examples at the begenning of the  doc on how to use it